# primefaces JSF p:selectOneMenu submitting null value

Tags: jsf, primefaces, seam

after researching for a while I still cannot find what I'm doing wrong.

I'm using Primefaces 3.5 with Seam. I have a selectOneMenu that is submitting a null value to the method `manualServiceRequestController.setService(Service service)`.
This is the .xhtml code:

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="service" value="#{manualServiceRequestController.service}">
    <f:converter converterId="serviceConverter" />
    <f:selectItems value="#{manualServiceRequestController.allServices}" />
    <p:ajax render="parameterPanel" event="change" process="@parent" partialSubmit="true" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

Thanks!

Comment: The problem should be in the converter, so show us the relevant converter code.

Comment: No, I've debugged converter and it also receives a null string to convert to object.

Comment: There is another funny thing, if I set `required="true"` to  `p:selectOneMenu`, the request is never sent to the server. I've also checked logs ( `<p:log>` ) and nothing unusual appears.

Comment: Strange enough. What's in the request parameter map then? Did you inspect it?

Comment: Could you provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) for that? Just reduce the problem to its minimum copy'paste'run version and post it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was the attribute `partialSubmit="true"`. I removed it and now the correct value is sent. I still don't understand exactly why.

Thanks **skuntsel** and **Xtreme Biker** for your responses.

Regards!